# How to iterate over the rows of a data frame?

Tags: r

I want to perform perform the following operations on a dataFrame in R

```
if(new$Period==0)
{
  print(" ")
  prevBal = new$EndingBalance

  print(new$LoanID)

  print(new$EndingBalance)

}else
{
  cat("else block execution")
  if(new$Period < 41)
  {

    if(new$NumberOfClaims>0)
    {
      cat("executing number of claims block")
      print((new$LossAmt)*(new$SimulationCount)/(new$NumberOfClaims)) #loss amount per claim
    }else
    {
      cat("executing else aftern no. of claims that prints 0")
      print(0)
    }
    print("end of if block point")
    print(new$BalanceInClaims) #balanceinclaims
    print(new$EndingBalance) #ending balance

  }
}
```

However, I get the warning in:

```
if (new$Period == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1
```

and only the first element will be used.
How do I make sure this is executed row by row?

Comment: Try to turn your operations into a function as use the `apply` family of functions to apply the functions over all rows.

Comment: I usually discourage the use of `apply` on a `data.frame`, at least until there is some clarity on something: `apply` converts the frame to a `matrix`, which has the often-undesirable side-effect of up-converting columns to what I call the least-usable state. If one of your columns is `character`, then everything is up-converted from logical, integer, and number into character, meaning any "math" will go wrong, and "comparisons" might be alphanumeric (meaning `"22" < "4"`, typically not what one means).

Comment: The reason you get that warning is that `if` requires a logical vector of length exactly 1, whereas if you have a frame of 2 or more rows, then you are passing a vector as long as the frame as rows. If you are looking over a frame row-wise, then you should likely be encompassing this in something like `for (rn in seq_len(nrow(new)))`, and then use `if (new$Period[rn] == 0) ...`.